# error validating xml file against xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate an xml file against xsd file 
but I get an error and I don't know why 
do anyone have an idea?

my xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
      <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:element ref="call"/>
            </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="cl">
      <xs:complexType>
           <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                   <xs:element ref="arguments"/>
                   <xs:element ref="outputs"/>
           </xs:choice>
           <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
           <xs:attribute name="module" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
           <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
      </xs:complexType> 
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="">
       <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                 <xs:element ref=""/>
          </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType> 
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="">
   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          xs:element ref=""/>
    </xs:choice>
   </xs:complexType>    
  </xs:element>


  <xs:element name="">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I get 'invalid file ' and I don't see where the problem is can anyone help me please?
thank you

Comment: I believe the Python code is not necessary to answer your question (so you can actually remove it, as well as the `python` tag.) The validation error is: `cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'outputs'. No child element is expected at this point.` You could change your code to print the parser error, instead of `invalid file` which gives you no information about the error.

Comment: how can I change my code to print the parser error I don't understand can you explain more? @helderdarocha

Comment: I don't use much PHP, but I believe you have to somehow have access to LibXMLError to print the messages. I found [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-validxphp/index.html?ca=drs) which might help if you are interested (it has a section on parser error reporting)

Comment: Your schema document appears to be invalid (in addition to having the problem identified by helderdarocha):  you've got four element declarations with empty names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance is not valid because, according to your Schema, you can only have a `choice` of one of `arguments` or `options` in your `call` element:

```
<xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
     <xs:element ref="arguments"/>
     <xs:element ref="outputs"/>
</xs:choice>
```

So, this is valid:

```
<call name="name" module="module" title="title">
    <outputs>
        <output name="name"/>
    </outputs>
</call>
```

And this is valid:

```
<call name="name" module="module" title="title">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="NAME" value="value"/>
    </arguments>
</call>
```

But this is not, since there is a constraint for a maximum and minimum of one element:

```
<call name="name" module="module" title="title">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="NAME" value="value"/>
    </arguments>
    <outputs>
        <output name="name"/>
    </outputs>
</call>
```

You might want to replace the `choice` with a `sequence` or increase it's `maxOccurs`/`minOccurs` values (depending on the structure you want to have).